# Assigning View Helpers ZF 1.12

Tags: zend-framework, model-view-controller, zend-framework-mvc

I can't get view helpers to work. This is what I've done so far:

I added this in application.ini

```
resources.view.helperPath.My_View_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/helpers"
```

In directory application/helpers I put the file findurl.php

Inside findurl.php I put

```
<?php
class My_View_Helper_findurl extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function findUrl($url){
         $url = $url;
         return htmlspecialchars($url);
    }
}
?>
```

Then in a view.phtml file I tried $this->findurl("http://google.com"); and got no luck, page goes blank.

I know I'm probably getting naming conventions wrong, could anyone help me out? Thank you.

I also tried this in view.phtml

```
$helper = $this->_helper->getHelper('findurl');
echo $helper->findUrl("http://google.com");
```

Comment: Check the error log to see what the actual error is, but `findurl.php` should certainly be `Findurl.php`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try renaming the filename. Edit: No luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->findurl('url');
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html

Comment: Thanks for this. I realized what I needed was to have the name Findurl.php like Tim had mentioned. then have a function findUrl which matched the class name, and get rid of _helper.